# Compare two .csv file and write diff into 3rd file

Tags: csv, file-comparison

I have two .csv files test_case_list.csv and test_case_summary.csv and I want to generate a third file that will have the difference of two files.

`test_case_list.csv` looks like:

```
cli-verify-cvlan-rewrite    ./vlan/vlan_rewrite_review.xls
cli-verify-cvlan-rewrite-lag    ./vlan/vlan_rewrite_review.xls
cli-verify-aggregation-general  ./link-aggr/aggregation.xls
```

`test_case_summary.csv` looks like:

```
*   cli-verify-aggregation-general  ./link-aggr/aggregation.xls
*   cli-verify-cvlan-rewrite    ./vlan/vlan_rewrite_review.xls
```

output: Another .xls or .csv file with

```
cli-verify-cvlan-rewrite-lag    ./vlan/vlan_rewrite_review.xls
```

Comment: diff a.csv b.csv > c.diff

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` and `sed`:

```
grep -v -F -f <(sed 's/^[*[:space:]]*//' test_case_summary.csv) test_case_list.csv > diff.csv
```

The `sed` command removes all leading `*` and whitespace characters from `test_case_summary.csv` and this output is used as 
input for `grep`'s `-f` option specifying a pattern file.

Option `-F` is used to interpret the patterns as fixed strings instead of regular expressions and `-v` selects non-matching lines, i.e. lines in `test_case_list.csv` which are *not* given in the pattern file. The output is then redirected to file `diff.csv`.

Additionally, you could add `grep`'s `-x` option to only match whole lines.

Comment: This command is producing an empty file...

Comment: Make sure `test_case_summary.csv` doesn't contain any blank/empty lines.